# Does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments when it does

Tags: c#, constructor

I'm having trouble getting the main to read my constructor.  It keeps saying my class doesn't contain a constructor that takes on 3 arguments. It's public. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I've done this before successfully, this is a practice problem I'm using to study for my test.

```
public class Actor
{
    //attributes 
    private string name;
    private int awardsNum;
    private bool SAGMember;

    //property 

    private string name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }

    }


    //constructor 

    public Actor(string Name, int AwardsNum, bool SAGMember)
    {
        this.name = Name;
        this.awardsNum = AwardsNum ++;
        this.SAGMember = false;
    }

    public Actor()
    {
    this.name = "Bob Smith";
    this.awardsNum = 0 ;
    this.SAGMember = false;
    }

    public override string ToString ()
    {
        return string.Format ("Actor: " + name + "\n" + " Number of Awards: " + awardsNum + "\n"+ "SAG Member: " + SAGMember);
    }

}


public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Actor a1 = new Actor ("Dustin Hoffman", 0 , true);
            Console.WriteLine (a1);

            Actor a2 = new Actor ();
            Console.WriteLine (a2);
        }
```

Comment: Also, the SAGMEMBER parameter in the ctor is the same as the local field SAGMEMBER

Comment: there is no `SAGMEMBER` property in the actor class, there is a `SAGMember` property however.

Comment: @Andrew, that was just changed.

Comment: @Jason, now the line `this.SAGMEMBER = false;` is not pointing at anything.  Why don't you get this cleaned up so it will at least compile, and then repost with new fresh compilable code.  Start simple and build it back up slowly. Read the compiler errors.

Comment: @CharlesBretana I never saw what it used to be before it was changed, but it definitely is a problem, which I see you stated right after I did.

Comment: @Andrew, yes, no worries!

Comment: Switched to visual studio rather than monodev, got it cleaned up and running now.

Answer (score 7):

I think your Actor class isn't compiling because of this line:

```
     set { name = Dustin Hoffman; }
```

and the JIT error is just confused because just how broken your code is as a result.

Also:

```
  Console.WriteLine("The Crowd applauds for " + name "with" + awardsNum "awards" );
```

Cannot simply sit out in no-man's land, it must be inside some kind of method or constructor.

Per comment below: you declare name as both a field and Property with the same capitalization, which is invalid. And it's declared SAGMember but referenced SAGMEMBER.

You do realize there is an error window in Visual Studio, right?

Comment: Also the `name` is declared twice and SAGMember has different capitalizations.

Comment: He's missing some + too.

Answer (score 2):

You actually have multiple compile errors. I suggest starting at the top error and working down. In this case, as @JasonLind suggested, the error message with the lack of a constructor is probably incorrect - occasionally you'll see cases like this where a previous compile error confuses the compiler (which is why you usually want to start with the first compile error - sometimes fixing one compile error will fix several others as well).

For example:

```
 Console.WriteLine("The Crowd applauds for " + name "with" + awardsNum "awards" );
```

You're missing a +. Also, as indicated, that has to be inside a method.

Also, as indicated:

```
 set { name = Dustin Hoffman; }
```

needs quotes. You shouldn't do that anyway because you can't set the property to anything but "Dustin Hoffman".

Also, `name` is declared twice. Make the property and field have different names.

Also, in your constructor:

```
this.awardsNum = AwardsNum ++;
    this.SAGMember = false;
```

Why the ++? Also, you always throw away the value that was passed into the constructor because `SAGMember` is hardcoded to `false`.

For the `ToString` method,

```
    return string.Format ("Actor: " + name + "\n" + " Number of Awards: " + awardsNum + "\n"+ "SAG Member: " + SAGMember);
```

You're not using a format string here, just concatenation. Also, why is `\n` a separate string?

The following comment:

```
//attributes
```

is incorrect. These are fields, not attributes - they're very different.

Comment: I've always preferred `Environment.NewLine` or using a `StringBuilder` with `.AppendLine()` for inserting line breaks, over escaping the new line character, but that's just mostly personal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Actor
{
    //Fields 
    /*Write a class “Actor” that contains these attributes with the appropriate level of visibility explicitly defined: 
    “Name” which is a String, 
    “numberOfAwards” which is an integer
    “SAGMember” which is a bool*/

    private string name;
    private bool SAGMember;
    private int awardsNum;



    //property
    //4.Write a property (get/set) for the name attribute ONLY.

    private string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }

    }

    //constructor
    // Write a parameterless constructor for this class that initializes the name to “Bob Smith”, the number of awards to 0, and the SAGMember to “false”.  
    public Actor()
    {
        this.name = "bob smith";
        this.SAGMember = false;
        this.awardsNum = 0;
    }

    public Actor(string name, bool SAGMember, int awardsNum)
    {
        this.name = Name;
        this.SAGMember = true;
        this.awardsNum = 4;
    }


    // over ride 
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Actor: " + name + "\n" +  "\n" + "SAG Member: " + SAGMember + "Number of Awards: " + awardsNum );
    }


}
```

-----MAIN------

```
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {

        Actor a1 = new Actor ( "Dustin Hoffman", true, 5);
        Console.WriteLine (a1);

        Actor a2 = new Actor ();
        Console.WriteLine (a2);
    }
}
```